# How to force windows 10 use different hardware's driver

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers

I'm using Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 and I notice that my computer doesn't have **Random hardware addresses** option. I looked around and found [this post](https://www.mathyvanhoef.com/2016/03/how-mac-address-randomization-works-on.html)

According to his post

> If you have an Intel 7260 AC, you can also force Windows 10 to use the drivers of the Intel 7265 AC. Your device will still work, and will support MAC address randomization.

But I can't find anyway to do it

Comment: Have you tried updating the driver using device manager? How you "force" w10 to do anything is a wild guess.

Comment: Are you using Windows 10 Defender?  Microsoft Enhanced Mitigation Experience Toolkit (EMET) is built into Defender and includes Address Randomization and other low level security protections. That probably does what you need. I am using the same Wireless card here.